# How to send a 2 Django view context objects to single html template in Django?

Tags: django

Please help me, I'm working on a project where I need to display a page about tutors and need to add their ratings also.so I created 2 models and 2 views for both tutors but I don't know how to display the context objects of both views in a single template.

```
class tutors(models.Model):

category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='tutors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
Tagline = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
description_tutor = models.TextField(blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
images=models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
qualification=models.TextField(null=True)

class Meta:
   ordering = ('name', )
   index_together = (('id', 'slug'),) 
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('onlinetutors:tutor_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

class ratings(models.Model):

```
username= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
rating=models.FloatField()
tutorname=models.ForeignKey(tutors,related_name='ratingss',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
```

def tutor_detail(request, id, slug):

```
tutor = get_object_or_404(tutors, id=id, slug=slug)

context = {
    'tutor': tutor,
}
return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

def rating(request,tutorname_id):

```
display_rating = ratings.objects.filter(tutorname_id=tutorname_id).aggregate(find_average=Avg('rating')) 
display = display_rating["find_average"]
return render(request, 'detail.html',{'display':display})
```

Answer (score 0):

when you `return render(request..`, you can set your dictionary to return multiple querysets. Filter your model objects as you did for ratings, then call them to your context dict.

`display_rating = ratings.objects.filter(..`
`display_tutors = tutors.objects.filter(..`
`return render(request, '.html', {'rating': display_rating, 'tutors': display_tutors}`

Also, make sure to capitalize your models since they are classes if you haven't already in your actual project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added both query sets in a single view.

Answer (score 0):

Added ratings query set into the existing tutors views function then sending both contexts to a single template. It is working now.

```
def Tutor_Detail(request, id, slug,tutorname_id=None):
tutor = get_object_or_404(tutors, id=id, slug=slug)


display_rating = ratings.objects.filter(tutorname_id = id).aggregate(find_average=Avg('rating'))
display_rating = display_rating['find_average']
context = {
    'tutor': tutor,
    'display':display_rating,
    
}
return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```